# Installing Ubuntu 18.04 alongside 17.10

Tags: dual-boot, usb, 18.04

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 alongside 17.10.
Is it normal to be waiting for this for more than 20 minutes? I hit continue and have been waiting here for a long time with no feedback.

Comment: Just to confirm, you created a new partition to install Ubuntu 18.04 and are keeping the original 17.10 partition?  Ubuntu 17.10 reached End of Life (EOL) a few days ago on **July 19, 2018**.

Comment: If installing to a slow flash drive the full install takes about 45 min. But to my SSD less than 10 min. That is to a previously formatted partition and using Something Else to only choose / (root) partition. But it shows activity the entire time, with only minor delays. To see how far you got: Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info